# Flutter list displaying erratically

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, listview, dart

I am having a problem with my lists in flutter not consistently keeping the order that I give them. I have a list: `List alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];`, and am trying to display it with ListView.builder like this:

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
itemCount: alphabet.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
return Center(
child: Text(alphabet[index]));
})
```

Usually this displays as "a b c d", but not always, sometimes it loads as "d, a, b, c" which is not acceptable. Once, it even came out as "d, a, c, b". How can I make it load the first way consistently?

I also have this line of code: `var letterA = (alphabet).first;`. Likewise it usually displays "a" but sometimes will display "d".

I couldn't find anything online about this problem, so I guess it is a silly mistake somewhere. I changed the page that includes the ListView from Stateful to Stateless hoping it would help but it didn't at all. And now I don't know what to do?

I could break up all my lists and write them letter by letter each time but I feel that is not the correct solution to my problem.

Edit:
Both alphabet and letterA are in a dart file together "mylists.dart" that just have that data, and then I imported it into this file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterproject/mylists.dart';
import 'package:flutterproject/nextpage.dart';

class AlphabetPage2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () =>   Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NextPage(),
                ),
              ),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: alphabet.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                              return Center(
                                  child: Text(alphabet[index]));
                            })),
                  ),
        ));
  }
}
```

mylists.dart looks like this:

```
List alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var letterA = (alphabet).first;

List soups = ['tomato', 'chicken noodle', 'lentil'];
var soupA = (soups).first;
```

The order, though usually correct is not always correct. And in other pages when I call soupA I mostly get tomato, but sometimes get another one.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This will help you find your mistake faster and if you don't, when you post it here, it will help us to help you find it faster.

Comment: Could you show more code, including where `alphabet` is created?

Comment: Its hard to reproduce because sometimes it is in the right order that I wrote, and sometimes not. I have lists with alphabet and lists with words. I would like it to keep the order I gave.

Comment: did you try sorting the list

    alphabet.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b))

Comment: Can you show how the `alphabet` is defined?

Comment: I added more code to the original post.

Comment: You surely are mutating the list somewhere.  Where and how do you modify it?

Comment: I am not modifying it at all. I am just calling it from the mylist.dart and trying to display it with ListView like I showed above. Most of the time it comes in the right order and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Usually it shows up in the correct order, but annoyingly not always.

Comment: Sorry if I'm skeptical that you don't modify the lists.  If you declare your lists as `const`, do you get the same erratic behavior?

Comment: I changed the list to const and then realized it messed up other places I was shuffling the list. I didn't realize the actual list was being shuffled--i thought I could call a shuffled version only when I wanted a shuffled one. But it seems like with the const it and a separate none-const version to shuffle I am not having any more problems. Thanks a lot!